# Updating Redmine issue using ActiveResource

Tags: ruby, redmine, activeresource

I want to update some **Redmine** issue using **ActiveResource**.

For example, a loaded ActiveResource object:

```
require 'active_resource'
require 'pp'

issue = Issue.find(id: 48549)
pp issue.attributes
```

output:

```
{"status"=>
  #<Issue::Status:0x2ebc8e8
   @attributes={"name"=>"New", "id"=>1},
   @persisted=false,
   @prefix_options={}>,
 "custom_fields"=>
  [#<Issue::CustomField:0x03bb188
    @attributes={"value"=>"", "name"=>"Code Reviewer", "id"=>38},
    @persisted=false,
    @prefix_options={}>,
   #<Issue::CustomField:0x3538518
    @attributes={"value"=>"1000", "name"=>"Inner Priority", "id"=>47},
    @persisted=false,
    @prefix_options={}>,
   #<Issue::CustomField:0x3536280
    @attributes={"value"=>"", "name"=>"Team", "id"=>87},
    @persisted=false,
    @prefix_options={}>],
 "done_ratio"=>100,
 "updated_on"=>"2014/07/22 17:22:40 +0300",
 "start_date"=>"2014/06/29",
 "description"=>"TEST - TEST - TEST",
 "author"=>
  #<Issue::Author:0x352fe48
   @attributes={"name"=>"Idit", "id"=>279},
   @persisted=false,
   @prefix_options={}>,
 "created_on"=>"2014/06/29 16:31:31 +0300",
 "id"=>48549,
 "subject"=>"This is a subject"}
```

The problem is, when i'm trying to update not a 'standard' attribute, such as the 'subject' or the 'description', which are simple strings.

On the 'status' attribute, for example, i can set the Issue::Status object and therefore the whole issue object,  **but i can't save this change on the source Redmine issue**.

The weird thing is that the object is saved successfully: `issue.save` returns true.

How should it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://rubygems.org/gems/redmine_client for that it is wrapper around ActiveResource and will give you ability to change that fields w/o pain. Only one known problem is to upload files  via that gem.